# How to get the second from LocalDateTime objects in a method with return type LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a problem with getting the seconds from two LocalDateTime objects.

```
// a timestammp for the time when the connection was established
public LocalDateTime establish() {

    startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    connectionEstablished = true;

    return startTime;
}

// timestamp for the time when the connection was disconnected
public LocalDateTime disconnect() {

    endTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    connectionDisconnected = true;

    return endTime;
}
// get the second when the connection was established
public LocalDateTime getStartTime() {

}

// get the seconds when the connection was disconnected
public LocalDateTime getEndTime() {

}
```

In the method getStartTime() and getEndTime the return type must be from LocalDateTime.
I tried different things, for example using Duration.between, using Temporal as return type but it does not work, because the Junit Test gives a error that the return type must be LocalDateTime.

Here is the Junit Test:

```
    @Test
void test() throws InterruptedException {
    cdr.establish();
    System.out.println(cdr.toString());
    assertTrue(cdr.toString().matches("calling: \\+44 44\\/725 8912, called: \\+1 982\\/543 1201, start: " + TIMESTAMP_PATTERN + ", end: still established"));
    assertEquals(0.0, Duration.between(cdr.getStartTime(), LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds(), 0.1);
    assertNull(cdr.getEndTime());
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    cdr.establish();
    // it fails here
    assertEquals(1.0, Duration.between(cdr.getStartTime(), LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds(), 0.1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
            cdr.disconnect();
    System.out.println(cdr.toString());
    assertTrue(cdr.toString().matches("calling: \\+44 44\\/725 8912, called: \\+1 982\\/543 1201, start: " + TIMESTAMP_PATTERN + ", end: " + TIMESTAMP_PATTERN));
    assertEquals(2.0, Duration.between(cdr.getStartTime(), cdr.getEndTime()).getSeconds(), 0.1);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    cdr.disconnect();
    assertEquals(2.0, Duration.between(cdr.getStartTime(), cdr.getEndTime()).getSeconds(), 0.1);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: Why are you asserting it to be 1 second before now, _before_ waiting one second?

Comment: The junit Test is given (it's not from me) and I need to implement the classes, which I did but with this Test I don't know how to proceed ...

Comment: Oh I see, the intention of the test is to make sure that the start time doesn't get reset after a second call to `establish`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the number of seconds between two local date times correctly. The intention of the test is to ensure that when `establish` is called a second time (i.e. when the connection is already established), `startTime` is not reset. The test basically says:

> One second later, establish the connection again, the start time should be 1 second before now (, as opposed to exactly now).

You should probably change the `establish`  method:

```
public LocalDateTime establish() {
    if (!connectionEstablished) { // add this check
        startTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    connectionEstablished = true;

    return startTime;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand why :)  I used if (!connectionEstablished) in getStartTime() and getEndTime() but It was not working...

Comment: @kannzzmm2 I just realised that you have a `connectionEstablished` as well as a `connectionDisconnected` variable. Can a connection be established _and_ disconnected at the same time? Can a connection be not established _and_ not disconnected at the same time? I think you can just use a single variable here. You should check `!connectionEstablished` in `getStartTime` and `connectionEstablished` in `getEndTime`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `assertEquals` try `assertTrue`.

Here is an example:

```
assertTrue(Duration.between(cdr.getStartTime(), LocalDateTime.now()).getSeconds() >= 1L);
```

Note that `getSeconds` returns a `long` value and that `1.0` is not a `long` value.